# Different file system types in fdisk; no HPFS/NTFS

Tags: partitioning, 15.10, ntfs, fdisk

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 and trying to format a USB drive to load a Windows ISO on. Every tutorial has you install ntfs-3g so that you can format to NTFS using fdisk, hex code 7. But when I go to fdisk and list the file system options, they are different than what is reported elsewhere:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114485/fdisk-l-shows-ext3-file-system-as-hpfs-ntfs
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=847318

The results from my fdisk file systems list is below. Is there something wrong with the USB drive that won't allow it to use the other file system types? Or am I missing some additional driver/software?

```
Command (m for help): t
Selected partition 1
Hex code (type L to list all codes): L
1 EFI System                     C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
2 MBR partition scheme           024DEE41-33E7-11D3-9D69-0008C781F39F
3 Intel Fast Flash               D3BFE2DE-3DAF-11DF-BA40-E3A556D89593
4 BIOS boot                      21686148-6449-6E6F-744E-656564454649
5 Microsoft reserved             E3C9E316-0B5C-4DB8-817D-F92DF00215AE
6 Microsoft basic data           EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
7 Microsoft LDM metadata         5808C8AA-7E8F-42E0-85D2-E1E90434CFB3
8 Microsoft LDM data             AF9B60A0-1431-4F62-BC68-3311714A69AD
9 Windows recovery environment   DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC
10 IBM General Parallel Fs        37AFFC90-EF7D-4E96-91C3-2D7AE055B174
11 Microsoft Storage Spaces       E75CAF8F-F680-4CEE-AFA3-B001E56EFC2D
12 HP-UX data                     75894C1E-3AEB-11D3-B7C1-7B03A0000000
13 HP-UX service                  E2A1E728-32E3-11D6-A682-7B03A0000000
14 Linux swap                     0657FD6D-A4AB-43C4-84E5-0933C84B4F4F
15 Linux filesystem               0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4
16 Linux server data              3B8F8425-20E0-4F3B-907F-1A25A76F98E8
17 Linux root (x86)               44479540-F297-41B2-9AF7-D131D5F0458A
18 Linux root (x86-64)            4F68BCE3-E8CD-4DB1-96E7-FBCAF984B709
19 Linux reserved                 8DA63339-0007-60C0-C436-083AC8230908
20 Linux home                     933AC7E1-2EB4-4F13-B844-0E14E2AEF915
21 Linux RAID                     A19D880F-05FC-4D3B-A006-743F0F84911E
22 Linux extended boot            BC13C2FF-59E6-4262-A352-B275FD6F7172
23 Linux LVM                      E6D6D379-F507-44C2-A23C-238F2A3DF928
24 FreeBSD data                   516E7CB4-6ECF-11D6-8FF8-00022D09712B
25 FreeBSD boot                   83BD6B9D-7F41-11DC-BE0B-001560B84F0F
26 FreeBSD swap                   516E7CB5-6ECF-11D6-8FF8-00022D09712B
27 FreeBSD UFS                    516E7CB6-6ECF-11D6-8FF8-00022D09712B
28 FreeBSD ZFS                    516E7CBA-6ECF-11D6-8FF8-00022D09712B
29 FreeBSD Vinum                  516E7CB8-6ECF-11D6-8FF8-00022D09712B
30 Apple HFS/HFS+                 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
31 Apple UFS                      55465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
32 Apple RAID                     52414944-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
33 Apple RAID offline             52414944-5F4F-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
34 Apple boot                     426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
35 Apple label                    4C616265-6C00-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
36 Apple TV recovery              5265636F-7665-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
37 Apple Core storage             53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
38 Solaris boot                   6A82CB45-1DD2-11B2-99A6-080020736631
39 Solaris root                   6A85CF4D-1DD2-11B2-99A6-080020736631
40 Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS       6A898CC3-1DD2-11B2-99A6-080020736631
41 Solaris swap                   6A87C46F-1DD2-11B2-99A6-080020736631
42 Solaris backup                 6A8B642B-1DD2-11B2-99A6-080020736631
43 Solaris /var                   6A8EF2E9-1DD2-11B2-99A6-080020736631
44 Solaris /home                  6A90BA39-1DD2-11B2-99A6-080020736631
45 Solaris alternate sector       6A9283A5-1DD2-11B2-99A6-080020736631
46 Solaris reserved 1             6A945A3B-1DD2-11B2-99A6-080020736631
47 Solaris reserved 2             6A9630D1-1DD2-11B2-99A6-080020736631
48 Solaris reserved 3             6A980767-1DD2-11B2-99A6-080020736631
49 Solaris reserved 4             6A96237F-1DD2-11B2-99A6-080020736631
50 Solaris reserved 5             6A8D2AC7-1DD2-11B2-99A6-080020736631
51 NetBSD swap                    49F48D32-B10E-11DC-B99B-0019D1879648
52 NetBSD FFS                     49F48D5A-B10E-11DC-B99B-0019D1879648
53 NetBSD LFS                     49F48D82-B10E-11DC-B99B-0019D1879648
54 NetBSD concatenated            2DB519C4-B10E-11DC-B99B-0019D1879648
55 NetBSD encrypted               2DB519EC-B10E-11DC-B99B-0019D1879648
56 NetBSD RAID                    49F48DAA-B10E-11DC-B99B-0019D1879648
57 ChromeOS kernel                FE3A2A5D-4F32-41A7-B725-ACCC3285A309
58 ChromeOS root fs               3CB8E202-3B7E-47DD-8A3C-7FF2A13CFCEC
59 ChromeOS reserved              2E0A753D-9E48-43B0-8337-B15192CB1B5E
60 MidnightBSD data               85D5E45A-237C-11E1-B4B3-E89A8F7FC3A7
61 MidnightBSD boot               85D5E45E-237C-11E1-B4B3-E89A8F7FC3A7
62 MidnightBSD swap               85D5E45B-237C-11E1-B4B3-E89A8F7FC3A7
63 MidnightBSD UFS                0394Ef8B-237C-11E1-B4B3-E89A8F7FC3A7
64 MidnightBSD ZFS                85D5E45D-237C-11E1-B4B3-E89A8F7FC3A7
65 MidnightBSD Vinum              85D5E45C-237C-11E1-B4B3-E89A8F7FC3A7
```

Answer (score 3):

It wasn't a problem that your partition was set to GPT. NTFS partition is actualy one of the `Microsoft basic data` partitions under number `6`. Read the wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_basic_data_partition).

Comment: Used today for the same purpose and on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS the `Microsoft Basic data` was number 11. Worth checking the list before just selecting a number. That worked fine with `mkfs.ntfs -f /dev/sdd1`

Answer (score 1):

It seems my problem was that the Partition Table was set to gpt. Changing it to msdos via gparted solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You use 7 for mbr partition table,
but for gpt partition table you need to use 6 Microsoft basic data